# When uploading file chunks are they guaranteed to be received in the same order?

Tags: servicestack, dropzone.js

Javascript front end, servicestack back end.

I'm using the latest version of dropzone.js to upload large image files (up to 50GB). The file is broken into many chunks and the server receives them one by one.  When I receive the last chunk I know I have the complete file and can begin processing. But what if the  chunks don't arrive in order?  Once the data leaves the client is it possible, due to internet routing, that the chunks could be received out of order?

The server side (service stack) has no persistence between calls (that I'm aware of) so I can't count chunks received (at least not without writing to a database or something).

Is this something I need to be concerned with and what is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know how the file chunks are sent in order to know how to handle them, e.g. whether they're using standard [HTTP multipart/formdata File Uploads](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867) in which case they'll be available in [ServiceStack's Request.Files collection](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#uploading-files) or some other way like sending raw bytes, in which case your [Request DTO will need to implement IRequiresStream](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream) to access the raw unserialized bytes.

The server can't guarantee how clients will send it, if it's guaranteed that clients only sends the chunks sequentially then the server can assume that's how it will always be sent, but for all the server knows the chunks can be sent concurrently, unordered and in parallel which it may need to support.

I'd personally avoid uploading files in chunks over independent HTTP API requests as it adds a tonne of complexity, but if the files can be up to `50GB` then you're going to need to come up with a bespoke solution.

You would handle the chunks just as you would any chunked data (e.g. imagine if you had to stitch responses from several services together manually). Because the files can be so large storing them in memory (like a ConcurrentDictionary) is not an option. If you have access to a cloud storage service you may want to upload the temporary chunks in there, otherwise you'd need to store them on disk. Ideally your solution should take advantage of the final data storage solution where the file will persist.

Otherwise a naive solution would be that the server should generate a unique key like a Guid before the client uploads the file that the client would need to send along with the chunk index and total chunks that needs to be sent. Each Service would then be writing that chunk directly to disk, first at a temp file path (`Path.GetTempFileName()`) then after the file is written move it to a format like `/uploads/{unique-id}/{chunk-index}.dat`.

Either at the end of every chunk upload request, you can check that your `/uploads/{unique-id}/` directory has all the chunks, if it does start the process of stitching it up and creating a single file. Although a more robust way would be for the client to initiate the file stitching after it's finished uploading all the chunks, that way if the stitch fails you can just manually call the service that stitches the files again, instead of needing to have the client re-upload the file.

Comment: I was adding the chunks to the target file as they were received.  Your suggestion of saving the chunks individually actually provides the mechanism to detect when all the chunks have arrived.  If I have totalChunks number of file parts then the uploaded in complete and I can stitch them together. There is the problem of notifying the sender that the server processing was successful, so an API call from the client after all chunks have been upload seems appropriate (chunksUploaded in dropzone).